# Purpose of backslash before file path

Tags: bash, ssh

The user account setup in our servers has the following restriction (for security reasons): First I have to ssh into the server with my user-id, say 'raja' and then I have to login as another user, say 'dev'. The 'dev' user is common for all of our team members and all the server operations are carried out as this user.

I am trying to tail a log file from my local machine with this command,

```
ssh -t uat4 'sudo -S -p "sudo password: " -u "dev" /bin/bash -l -c "tail -f \$HOME/application/log/uat.log"'
```

This works. I got this command from python fabric's `sudo('tail -f $HOME/application/log/uat.log', user=dev)`, using `--show=debug` flag.

But when I tried to do this **without the backslash (in front of $HOME)**, like

```
ssh -t uat4 'sudo -S -p "sudo password: " -u "dev" /bin/bash -l -c "tail -f $HOME/application/log/uat.log"'
```

I am getting this error message

> tail: cannot open
> `/home/raja/application/log/uat.log' for reading:
> Permission denied
>
> Connection to ma-retailmet-lapp04.corp.apple.com closed.

What is the purpose of this backslash in that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference between [escaping the character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) or not - try `echo "$HOME"` versus `echo "\$HOME"` in console to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for answering. `"$HOME"` gives me the path and `\"$HOME"` gives me the literal **$HOME** but in my case the `$HOME` variable is evaluated properly to the home path of the remote user. I have edited the question with more details. Can you please elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: If the `$HOME` was evaluated before the `sudo`, it would not expand to the `$HOME` of the user `dev`, but of the user running the `sudo`.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. I didn't pay attention to that. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?